# ¿Cómo puedo llamar una función desde el template con Django?

Tags: python, django, symfony2, twig

Resulta que recién comencé a desarrollar mis aplicaciones con *Django*, pues venía trabajando varios años en *PHP* con *Symfony* y ***Twig***.

En *Twig* se puede hacer una llamada a un `Action` de mis Controllers en *Symfony*.

#### Ejemplo:

```
{{ render(controller(MiController:Action)) }}
```

Esto me devuelve una vista con la lógica aplicada en el controller que se incluye en el *template* donde se hace el llamado.

Existe alguna manera de hacer esto en *Django*, digamos algo así, tal vez:

#### Folder: **templates/homepage.html

```
{% block fragment1 %}
 {{ render 'views.NombreVistaQueDevuelveOtraVista' }}
{% endblock %}
</code>
# mi vista: mi_app/views.py
<code>
def NombreVistaQueDevuelveOtraVista(request):
    data = MiModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'fragmento_vista.html', {'data': data})
```

Comment: Mmmmmm no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, ya que la podría responder de dos formas, digamos que si quieres reutilizar plantillas html, puedes usar un templatetag llamado `{% include %}`, si necesitas una función especifica creas un templatetag, de lo contrario si quieres cargar el contenido de una pagina en otra, puedes hacerlo con jquery.loads, si puedes ser más especifico en qué quieres, con gusto te ayudaria

Comment: Gracias ArtEze por  responder tan rápido... Como ya dije soy nuevo en Django... según tengo entendido hasta ahora con el {% include %} solo puedo cargar un html, sin la lógica de mi controller, lo que quisiera es poder incluir ese template pero ya con su contenido generado en el views

Comment: Puedes usar el `{% include %}` enviando los parametros que necesita el template para hacer lo que quiere, es decir, un template es simple html, que tiene unas etiquetas que django lee y resuelve lo que ve ya sea un if, un for una variable, puedes hacer eso mismo sin necesidad de llamar a la vista cuando haces un `{% include 'archivo.html' with variable=un_valor %}`

Answer (score 3):

Lo ideal es que en el template no haya lógica. La lógica la debería hacer en la vista y al template solo pasar los datos que necesita. Ya llegado a un caso (casi) extremo, sería crear un custom templatetag.

Answer (score 2):

No se sobre Symphone pero Laravel es el equivalente a Django en Php, como sea, en Django no se debe hacer lo que deseas hacer.

```
return render(request, 'fragmento_vista.html', {'data': data, 'otraview': NombreVistaQueDevuelveOtraVista(request)})
```

En tu template solo debes agregar:

```
{{ otraview }}
```

Pero repito **NO ES RECOMENDABLE**, mejor usa template tags.

Los templates en Django son solo para pintar trata siempre de manejar toda tu lógica a nivel las vistas.

[Template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: Recuerda que las funciones (vistas) de Django, siempre retornan objetos del tipo HttpResponse, por lo que enviar la vista directamente no está retornando el html, si no un objeto de respuesta http y en su contenido, tendrá el html

Comment: Esta utilizando una vista basada en funciones, puede regresar lo que quiera, al final es una función, solo tendria que regresar el html ya renderizando con la función  "render"

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder a una funcionalidad en la vista desde un template, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
{% block fragment1 %}
       {{ view.MiFuncion}}
{% endblock fragment1 %}
```

Comment: Bueno algo así como lo que dices es lo que intento hacer, donde MiFuncion renderice una template.html con la logica aplicada, pero mi duda está en como hacer referencia al view para accesar a sus funciones. Por otro lado voy a probar la opción que me comenta @German Alzate. Gracias a todos, les dejo saber cual me funcionó

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas directamente las clases genércias de Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/? Creo que te van a ser muy útiles para lo que buscas. Por ejemplo, tienes una clase asociada a un template y en esa clase, le defines la función que necesitas. Luego, desde template puedes invocar a esa función con la sentencia {{ view.Mifuncion }}

Answer (score 0):

si solo quieres dibujar otra vista, no hace falta llamar una funcion solo basta asignarla a un parametro de la vista.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
content = render_to_string(template_name, dictionary, context_instance)
```

Ahora bien si deseas algo mas dinamico deveras incursionar por peticiones AJAX